# How to change the destination directory of a downloaded document

Tags: c#, download, document

```
string Idd = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
    string DocName = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["Name"]);
    #region
    try
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite osite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = osite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        //LinkButton lnkView = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
                        //string Name = lnkView.CommandArgument;
                        //string ID = lnkView.ID;
                        SPDocumentLibrary library = web.Lists["Shared Documents"] as SPDocumentLibrary;
                        string filepath = library.RootFolder.Url;
                        string filename = DocName;
                        string IDofDoc = Idd;

                        //SPFile file = web.GetFile(library.RootFolder.Url + "/No Easy Day.pdf");
                        SPFile file = web.GetFile(filepath + "/" + filename);

                        Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                        //string filepath1 = fileStream.Name.Replace(fileStream.Name, @"~\\SAIDI\\" + "Asset//");
                        #region
                        //string filepath1 = (sender as Button).Command;
                        //Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                        //filepath1=MapPath(@"~\\SAIDI\\" +"Asset//"+filepath);
                        //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFullPath());
                        //Response.WriteFile(filepath1);
                        //Response.End();                         
                        //duplicate
                        #endregion
                        int buffer = 4096;
                        int read = buffer;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer];
                        while (read == buffer)
                        {
                            read = stream.Read(bytes, 0, buffer);
                            fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                            if (read < buffer) break;
                        }
                        stream.Dispose();
                        fileStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message + "<br>" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

Question is :- Downloaded Document is downloaded to

```
C:\windows\system32\inetsrv
```

1. How can I change the destination file path?
2. I have placed this code in production server, but, file is not downloaded.

What is the solution for those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you second question: The using-statement are effectivly try/catch-block (with some additional logic related to disposing object). I would suggest to replace the usings by explicit try/catch-blocks. That way you can catch the exeptions and log them to a file (or whatever is necessary).

Sascha

Answer (score 0):

```
string Idd = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["Id"]);
    string DocName = Convert.ToString(Page.Request.QueryString["Name"]);
    #region
    try
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite osite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = osite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        //LinkButton lnkView = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
                        //string Name = lnkView.CommandArgument;
                        //string ID = lnkView.ID;
                        SPDocumentLibrary library = web.Lists["Shared Documents"] as SPDocumentLibrary;
                        string filepath = library.RootFolder.Url;
                        string filename = DocName;
                        string IDofDoc = Idd;

                        //SPFile file = web.GetFile(library.RootFolder.Url + "/No Easy Day.pdf");
                        SPFile file = web.GetFile(filepath + "/" + filename);

                        Stream stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();

                        filename= Path.Combine(filepath, filename);

                        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                        //string filepath1 = fileStream.Name.Replace(fileStream.Name, @"~\\SAIDI\\" + "Asset//");
                        #region
                        //string filepath1 = (sender as Button).Command;
                        //Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                        //filepath1=MapPath(@"~\\SAIDI\\" +"Asset//"+filepath);
                        //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFullPath());
                        //Response.WriteFile(filepath1);
                        //Response.End();                         
                        //duplicate
                        #endregion
                        int buffer = 4096;
                        int read = buffer;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer];
                        while (read == buffer)
                        {
                            read = stream.Read(bytes, 0, buffer);
                            fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, read);
                            if (read < buffer) break;
                        }
                        stream.Dispose();
                        fileStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message + "<br>" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

1) How can i change the destination file path.?

You can pass the destination path as first parameter in [FileStream constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For example:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("D:\\" + filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

if you want to use common location, you can use [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```

2) i have placed this code in production server, but, file is not downloaded

I guess this is a permission issue. Try to write the file in another directory?

Comment: thank u for ur answer. First time it worked. after that, i am getting below error.                                                                                                         " The device is not ready. "

Comment: Ok . i got the answer. there is no D drive in my machine. i have given F.but, how can i mention common location like Downloads,library etc.if any user wants to download, he will face same issue. suggest me to download to :" Downloads(it is common in every system) folder only.

Comment: with ur edited answer, doc is saved on desktop. thank you iswanto

Comment: Yes. I accepted that answer. But, one more thing.It was working on live server not in my local machine(i opened same site and tried to download.But no luck). If it is a permission issue,i am  using admin credentials only. can u plz suggest me what i need to do?